# gsuite fail to authenticate postfix

Tags: postfix, g-suite

I have a ubuntu 18.04 running postfix to deliver mail with gsuite smtp.

I configured postfix following [this guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/email-services/configure-postfix-to-send-mail-using-gmail-and-google-apps-on-debian-or-ubuntu/) and followed all the steps to create a password specific for the postfix app.

I tried to send a test email but I still receive the following error:

> Sep 25 17:36:31 mail postfix/error[8970]: 8CF1C1E240:
> to=xxx.xxx@gmail.com, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0,
> dsn=4.7.8, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: SASL
> authentication failed; server smtp.gmail.com[74.125.71.109] said:
> 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at?535 5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f23sm3095998wmc.3 -
> gsmtp)

I also tried to reissue a new password but still I get the same error. I tried restarting the service (postfix) and also the server with no luck.

Any hint why I get this error?

Comment: Check the mail logs on your server.

Comment: Server log is already in the question. No other errors or issues for each attempt

Comment: You should have more log entries than that! Post the rest of them.